# why does the child template get overriden by the templates in extends when using the django framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

for login.html this is what I have

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Tryin to Log In</h2>
{% endblock content %}
```

for base.html this is what I have

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>base template</h2>
  
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that the base.html overwrites the templates in login.html
I have looked into the settings.py and this is what I have

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the child template? Where is it being used?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is That include inserts a template into the current one, and extend will declare the template given as an argument as the current template's parent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).